# How to merge multiple WebDAV accounts for backup?

Tags: linux, bash, backup, rsync, webdav

I use davfs, aufs, rsync:

```
sudo mount -t davfs -o uid=wd,gid=wd,dir_mode=777,rw https://wd1.wd.wd/ /mnt/webdav1
sudo mount -t davfs -o uid=wd,gid=wd,dir_mode=777,rw https://wd1.wd.wd/ /mnt/webdav2
sudo mount -t davfs -o uid=wd,gid=wd,dir_mode=777,rw https://wd2.wd.wd/ /mnt/webdav3
sudo mount -t aufs none /mnt/webdav/ -o br:/mnt/webdav1=rw:/mnt/webdav2=rw:/mnt/webdav3=rw,create=mfs,sum
rsync -r /home/user/bp /mnt/webdav/backup
```

But I have many problems:

1. aufs pumped into one stream on webdav server
2. rsync does not work resume files (tried - ignore-existing but not working)

Does anyone know how to fix these problems or advise other software? I thought of using ownCloud but I'm not sure whether it can unite WebDAV server into one for backup.

Answer (score 1):

1. aufs in mfs mode locks into the same branch for a default of 30 seconds, it will not check free space again until after that timeout, you can change timeout by using `create=mfs:<time>`. Also davfs might not fully support the statfs() system call, which aufs needs for mfs mode to check space, in that case you might want to change to `create=rr`.
2. Try adding `--update`, that only copies files that are newer; and possibly `--archive` to preserve attributes and special files; you should at least add `--times` (auto-added by `--archive`) to preserve the timestamps, so that rsync knows what files have changed since last backup.
   If you are keeping snapshots, you can add `--del` to remove files in the destination that are no longer in your source (e.g. home) directory.
   If you are currently using the account you are copying, there might be some fuse mounts active that can stop your copy, you can skip those using `--one-file-system` or simply `-x`.
   But really, if you do not need the special stuff that rsync gives you, you can do a simpler `cp -aux /home/user/bp/ /mnt/webdav/backup` instead.